# Why can't I put two obects belonging to different subclass but same super class into an array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, class, object, oop

this page
[Designing Heterogeneous Class Hierarchies](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/heterogeneous-arrays.html)
tells us that we can put two obects belonging to different subclass but same super class into an array.

But in my program, it doesn't work. In my program, I create a super class 'Agent' and two subclass 'Agent_XY' and 'Agent_XZ' inheriting 'Agent'. I let A to be an Agent_XY object and B to be an Agent_XZ object. And I try to put this two objects into an array.

```
classdef Agent < handle

    properties
        inventory_X
        inventory_Y
        inventory_Z
    end
    methods
        function obj = Agent(inventory_x,inventory_y,inventory_z)
            obj.inventory_X = inventory_x;
            obj.inventory_Y = inventory_y;
            obj.inventory_Z = inventory_z;
        end
    end
end
```

```
classdef Agent_XY < Agent
    properties

    end

    methods
        function obj = Agent_XY(inventory_x,inventory_y,inventory_z)
           obj = obj@Agent(inventory_x,inventory_y,inventory_z)
        end
    end
end
```

```
classdef Agent_XZ < Agent
    properties

    end

    methods
        function obj = Agent_XZ(inventory_x,inventory_y,inventory_z)
           obj = obj@Agent(inventory_x,inventory_y,inventory_z)
        end
    end
end
```

```
A=Agent_XY(1,2,3)

A = 

  Agent_XY with properties:

    inventory_X: 1
    inventory_Y: 2
    inventory_Z: 3

>> B=Agent_XZ(4,5,6)

B = 

  Agent_XZ with properties:

    inventory_X: 4
    inventory_Y: 5
    inventory_Z: 6
```

```
Array = [A,B]

Error using horzcat
The following error occurred converting from Agent_XZ to Agent_XY:
Not enough input arguments.
```

Why the program is going to convert class of B from Agent_XZ to Agent_XY? According to the page [Designing Heterogeneous Class Hierarchies](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/heterogeneous-arrays.html), [A,B] should form an array whose class is 'Agent'.
I try to verify whether the class of A or B is 'Agent', and it's true.

```
isa(A,'Agent')
ans =

  logical

   1

isa(B,'Agent')
ans =

  logical

   1
```

I have found the shortest code to reproduce similar problem

```
classdef Agent < handle
end

classdef Agent_XY < Agent
end

classdef Agent_XZ < Agent
end

A=Agent_XY
A = 

  Agent_XY with no properties.

B=Agent_XZ
B = 

  Agent_XZ with no properties.

C=[A,B]
Error using horzcat
The following error occurred converting from Agent_XZ to Agent_XY:
Too many input arguments.
```

This time it says 'Too many input arguments.'

Comment: The page you link clearly shows all classes having `matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous` as the superclass.

Comment: Thank you! The easiest way to put them into an array is to let them inherite  matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous